# aero glass blurred window not rendering properly

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

My main goal is to just make a simple blurred window and then draw my application on it.
But it is not documented by windows and my window has another blur behind it and text is not blended.

You can see the weird edges in this image:
[image: another blur on edges]
When i don't set the alpha using SetLayeredWindowAttributes:
[image: layered window without alpha]

here is the whole code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 1;

    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED,//WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 300,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
        return 1;

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, NULL, 255, LWA_ALPHA);

    typedef enum _WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB
    {
        WCA_UNDEFINED = 0,
        WCA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1,
        WCA_NCRENDERING_POLICY = 2,
        WCA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED = 3,
        WCA_ALLOW_NCPAINT = 4,
        WCA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS = 5,
        WCA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT = 6,
        WCA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION = 7,
        WCA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 8,
        WCA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP = 9,
        WCA_THEME_ATTRIBUTES = 10,
        WCA_NCRENDERING_EXILED = 11,
        WCA_NCADORNMENTINFO = 12,
        WCA_EXCLUDED_FROM_LIVEPREVIEW = 13,
        WCA_VIDEO_OVERLAY_ACTIVE = 14,
        WCA_FORCE_ACTIVEWINDOW_APPEARANCE = 15,
        WCA_DISALLOW_PEEK = 16,
        WCA_CLOAK = 17,
        WCA_CLOAKED = 18,
        WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19,
        WCA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION = 20,
        WCA_EVER_UNCLOAKED = 21,
        WCA_VISUAL_OWNER = 22,
        WCA_HOLOGRAPHIC = 23,
        WCA_EXCLUDED_FROM_DDA = 24,
        WCA_PASSIVEUPDATEMODE = 25,
        WCA_LAST = 26
    } WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB;

    typedef struct _WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA
    {
        WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB Attrib;
        PVOID pvData;
        SIZE_T cbData;
    } WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA;

    typedef enum _ACCENT_STATE
    {
        ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND = 4,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_HOSTBACKDROP = 5,
        ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 6
    } ACCENT_STATE;

    typedef struct _ACCENT_POLICY
    {
        ACCENT_STATE AccentState;
        DWORD AccentFlags;
        DWORD GradientColor;
        DWORD AnimationId;
    } ACCENT_POLICY;

    typedef BOOL(WINAPI* SetWindowCompositionAttribute)(
        IN HWND hwnd,
        IN WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA* pwcad);

    SetWindowCompositionAttribute lSetWindowCompositionAttribute;

    auto user32Lib = LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll");
    if (!user32Lib)
        return 1;

    lSetWindowCompositionAttribute = (SetWindowCompositionAttribute)GetProcAddress(user32Lib,"SetWindowCompositionAttribute");
    if (!lSetWindowCompositionAttribute)
        return 1;

    if (lSetWindowCompositionAttribute)
    {
        ACCENT_POLICY accent = { 
            ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND, 0, DWORD(L"FFFFFFFF"), 0
        };//not using acrylic because of a windows bug
        WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA data;
        data.Attrib = WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
        data.pvData = &accent;
        data.cbData = sizeof(accent);
        lSetWindowCompositionAttribute(hWnd, &data);
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, Windows desktop!");

    RECT wr;
    HBRUSH br;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &wr);
        br = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_APPWORKSPACE);
        FillRect(hdc, &wr, br);

        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also is it possible to get the frame buffer bitmap behind my window? that way i can blur it myself and the client area would have a fake glass effect.

Windows 10, Visual Studio, c++

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Using the back drop brush is documented (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor.createhostbackdropbrush), but you'll have to use Direct Composition (also called "the Visual Layer" (ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer note this is *not* limited to UWP contrary to what doc may say). The easiest way to do this today is to use WinUI3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks, does WinUI work for windows 10 and c++?

Comment: Yes it does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app